# MySQL fails update a record with utf8mb4 string on Jetty

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, jetty, gradle, utf8mb4

I'm running java over jetty, on an EC2 linux instance, using MySQL DB. The column is a VARCHAR, set to accept utf8mb4 encoding.

After playing around with stuff, I've found out that it works when I run this code through `gradle jettyRunWar`, or even when running the same code on a tomcat server.

It doesn't work when I place the exact same war that was working before in $JETTY_HOME/webapps/root.war, then run jetty with `sudo service jetty start`.

The error shown is -

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x99\x89' for column 'name' at row 1
```

Current column definition -

```
`name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL
```

Value is set in SQL through preparedStatement.setString(...) and I made sure that mysql connector JAR is the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem resolved once I've set all `character_set_...` MySQL DB variables to utf8mb4.**

That probably means that newer version of jetty (8+) treat JDBC connection different than Tomcat or than older version, because the exact connection string, beans definition & DB was used at all cases.

Until now, `character_set_...` params were set to utf8 with specific columns defined as utf8mb4, that used to be enough.

Hopes that saves anyone else the day I was stuck on it.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how did you solve it? I use following settings for mysql but still got the same error as you mentioned:`[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
`
Also, I can confirm it's OK to use JDBC java application to insert UTF8 chars, but just not from Jetty.

Thanks.